# show that the line and plane are parallel..

Tags: linear-algebra

its a really stupid question but i cant seem to solve it. a line1 is defined by $2$ equation, $2x-z=7$ and $2y+z=9$ and a plane  of $3x-y-2z=18$ is given. Now the question is to show that the line is parallel to the plane. I know the concept that for them to be parallel the dot product of normal of plane and the vector needs to be zero. But i dont understand the equations given for the line!! how do i know the vector ? please please help me out here
thanks!!

Comment: The vector $(2,0,-1)$ is perpendicular to the plane $2x+0y-z=7$. The vector $(0,2,1)$ is perpendicular to the plane $0x+2y+z=9$. Therefore the vector $(2,0,-1)\times (0,2,1)$ should be parallel to the intersection of those two planes. The vector $(3,-1,-2)$ is perpendicular to the plane $3x-y-2z=18$. If $((2,0,-1)\times (0,2,1))\cdot(3,-1,-2)=0$ then $(2,0,-1)\times (0,2,1)$ is perpendicular to $(3,-1,-2)$ and therefore parallel to the plane $3x-y-2z=18$.

Comment: The $\times$ is the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) and the $\cdot$ is the [dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).

Comment: Another possibility is to show that no point on the line lies in the plane, that is, the three equations have no simultaneous solution.

Comment: I'm sorry but i still don't get it.. how is the equation of line changed to plane 2x+0y-z=7 ? and by solving this the answer is not 0 however they are parallel and we need to prove it :/

Comment: @saulspatz It is not necessary for the line to lie in the plane, as it can be parallel with a **non-zero** distance.

Comment: Unfortunately, I feel I had to flag this. This isn’t a site that will solve problems **for** you, and some effort or examples of your own thoughts must be shown. That way, we can help you—and others—the best we can. For more information, please read [how to ask a good question](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ). At any rate, I wish the best of luck to you, and please continue to contribute to our wonderful site!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question. Drawing a picture may also help.

1. Every plane can be written in the form $\vec{n}\cdot \vec{x} = C$, where $\vec{n}$ is a constant vector that is perpendicular to the plane, $C$ is a number, and $\vec{x}$ is an arbitrary point $\langle x, y, z\rangle$. If $\vec{x}$ is a point that satisfies this equation, it's on the plane. Otherwise, it's not on the plane.
2. If we can rewrite your plane in this form, we'll be able to read off $\vec{n}$, the vector perpendicular to the plane. But indeed we can rewrite  $$3x - y - 2z = 18$$
   as

   $$\begin{bmatrix}3&-1&-2\end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix} = 18$$

   So, the vector $\vec{n} \equiv [3, -1, -2]$ is perpendicular to the plane.
3. Now the line is defined by two equations:  $2x-z=7$ and $2y+z=9$ (these are planes; their intersection gives the line).

   By the reasoning above, these two planes have normal vectors $\langle 2, 0, -1\rangle$ and $\langle 0, 2, 1\rangle$ respectively. If you envision two planes intersecting at a line in space, note that the line is parallel to both planes and therefore perpendicular to both normals.
4. To find a vector that is parallel to the line and perpendicular to both normals, we can take the cross product of both normals.

   $$\langle 2, 0, -1\rangle \times \langle 0, 2, 1\rangle = \langle 2, -2, 4\rangle$$.
5. Note that to show that the line is parallel to the plane, all we need to do is show that this vector $\langle 2, -2, 4\rangle$ is perpendicular to $\vec{n} = \langle 3, -1, -2\rangle$.
6. Note that $\langle 2, -2, 4\rangle \cdot \langle 3, -1, -2\rangle = 6 + 2 -8 = 0$, which establishes what we wanted to show.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your line into a parametric equation of a line.

You need $2$ points.

1) Add equations:

$2x+2y =16$ , or $x+y =8;$

2)$ z=2x-7;$

Points: $( 4,4,1)$,  $(5,3,3)$, for example.

$\vec r = (4,4,1) + t (1,-1,2)$;

where the direction vector:

$ \vec d =$

$ (5-4,3-4,3-1) =(1,-1,2)$

the vector pointing from

$(4, 4,1)$ to $(5,3,3).$

Show the line is parallel to the plane.

Normal vector of the plane :

$\vec n =(3,-1,-2)$.

Direction vector: $\vec d = (1,-1,2).$

Scalar product:

$\vec n \cdot \vec d= 3 +1 -4 =0.$

Hence line parallel to plane.